# Simple Numeric example to understand Pointwise Mutual Information

Tags: probability, pointwise-mutual-information

I have been trying to find a simple numerical example for PMI in order to understand the calculations, but I have not been able to find one. I have the following data (assuming there are more data, just with this data would be enough to understand):

|  | red | green | blue |  | P(w) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tulip | 0,02 | 0,01 | 0,05 |  | 0,08 |
| Rose | 0,02 | 0,03 | 0,02 |  | 0,08 |
| Marg | 0 | 0,04 | 0,05 |  | 0,04 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Total | 0,04 | 0,08 | 0,12 |  | 1 |

I am trying to calculate the PMI of the different values but I having difficulty knowing which value to apply in the PMI formula. Knowing a result beforehand, for Tulip-Red it would be `2.643856189`.

$$ \operatorname{PMI}(w, c) =  \log_2\frac{P(w, c)}{P(w)P(c)}$$

Comment: There are blind users of this site who use screen readers. The screen readers can’t handle images. Please use TeX for the formula and a Markdown table for the data. A tutorial on TeX for Stack Exchange is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Sure! I will proceed and edit the question asap! Sorry for the inconvenience! @AryaMcCarthy

Comment: If you truly want a *simple* (but non-trivial) example, use just a $2\times 2$ table.  The calculations become particularly simple in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue once upon a time. There is a very nice, clearly spelled out example in Manning & Schütze's Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing 178-181. In particular, the example on p. 179 considers an example where the corpus contains 14307668 tokens. It shows that for two words w1 and w2, if w1 appears 42 times in the corpus, w2 appears 20 times in the corpus, and if w1 and w2 co-occur (appear together) in the corpus 20 times, then PMI(w1, w2) = $$ \log_{2} \frac{\frac{20}{14307668}}{\frac{42}{14307668} \times \frac{20}{14307668}} $$

In your example, the probability of seeing tulip and red together is .02, the probability of seeing red on its own is .04, and the probability of seeing tulip on its own is .08. So the PMI is $$ \log_{2} \frac{.02}{.08 \times .04} $$ which is equal to the number you mention..